# Simultaneous pictures with iPhone 7 Plus cameras

Tags: ios, iphone, avcapturesession, avcapture, avcaptureoutput

Is there a way to take a picture with the Telephoto lens and the Wideangle lens of the iPhone 7 Plus ?

I explored the different methods, but the best I can come with is to change the camera by removing the input `AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInTelephotoCamera` and adding the input from `AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInWideangleCamera`. This takes about 0.5 second however, I would like to capture it simultaneouly. From a hardware point of view, it should be possible since Apple is doing the same when using the `AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInDuoCamera`.

Does anybody know other methods to capture a photo from both cameras at (almost) the same time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to capture from both cameras too, but what I've found is this:

> When you are using the AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInDualCamera that
>   automatically switches between wide and tele, they are synchronized to
>   the same clock. Simultaneous running of the
>   AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInTelephotoCamera and
>   AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInWideAngleCamera cameras is not supported.

Source - https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63347

Comment: Maybe someone will find it interesting (iOS11 + iPhone 7 Plus) ->
[Capturing Depth in iPhone Photography](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/507/)
Portrait mode on iPhone 7 Plus showcases the power of depth in photography. In iOS 11, the depth data that drives this feature is now available to your apps. Learn how to use depth to open up new possibilities for creative imaging. Gain a broader understanding of high-level depth concepts and learn how to capture both streaming and still image depth data from the camera.